# Ubuntu Microphone Not Working (18.04.1 LTS)

Tags: sound, 18.04, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS from 16.04 LTS, I noticed that my microphone is not functioning properly. I have checked to see if it was muted, used alsamixer, modified the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file, and unlocked the volume channels and setting one to zero and slightly above zero in `pavucontrol` using sudo and without sudo.

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7548.

The first edit I made to the `alsa-base.conf` file mentioned above was the addition of these two lines from a similar question I read here:

```
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

and this:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-vostro enable=1 index=0
```